# Issue with creating and editing json object

Tags: python, json

I am fairly inexperienced when it comes to working with json files. Firstly. I would like to achieve the following:

I post a specific job on a website, and If that job is successful, I want to store the data with its storage url in a json file. My current codes makes that maybe a little bit easier to understand:

```
if response.status_code == 201:
    storage_url = response.json()["url"]
    data = {}    
    
    with open("storage_dict.json", "w") as f:
        try:
            data = json.load(f)
        except Exception:
            json.dump(data, f)
        data[file_name] = {"storage_url": storage_url, "folder": input_folder}
```

My reasoning for this code is the following:

If the dictionary is no json file yet, I "create" a json file by dumping the empty dictionary. If the dict is already a json file (i.e. json.load()) is successful, I simply add the new entry to the json file. This code however does not work, since each new entry overwrites the old one. I would like to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know if the code here is typescript or javascript, but you should add the proper tag for better audience.

Comment: Where is defined `file_name` ?